# Google Maps: Why when I upload my app to playstore , and downloaded the Google Map is not shown?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am currently developing an app in android using a Google map. My map serves me correctly if I run it from my PC to my phone. The problem is when I upload the same APK up to the Play store and download the app, my map is not shown correctly. Does anyone know why?

- Currently I use the library Play Services.
- I have my API KEY = " XXXXXXXXXX "
- I have all the necessary permits ..

Does anyone have any idea why the map is not displayed correctly? (Sorry, I can't show my screenshot).

Comment: Did you add your release keystore hash to google map API? Looks like you have only specify the debug cert and not the one you use ifor playstore. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

Comment: Fixed formatting. Unfortunately no clear description was given of the map display issue, other than a failed attempt at adding a screenshot. If the poster adds a URL to the screenshot, a user of higher rep will be able to incorporate it into the port.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the Release Certificate fingerprint. It is specifically added when you want to to publish your app in the playstore. There are certain steps that you need to follow in order to get that. Expand the [displaying the release certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information) section and follow the steps.

Comment: You know if the Google Developers Console is the same procedure to take a certificate APY KEY debug and release certificate fingerprint fingerprint ?. In both it gives me a similar one. It gave me these keys.
• debug certificate fingerprint AIzaSyB3f1_hmg2aOwnWuZ9K4AckyjG5TyxGxyY
• release certificate fingerprint AIzaSIFSgfMK3Jh8sfJLNntqEfcP0O3eil9mqAU